# Rspec/Rails: how to verify that no method of a class is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'd like to write something like this:

```
it 'does not invoke any MyService' do
    MyService.should_not_receive(<any method>)
    tested_method
end
```

I do not want to list all methods of MyService explicitly because this would lead to a brittle test that could give false positives silently if new methods were added to MyService.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about replacing the implementation with a double?

```rb
it 'does not invoke any MyService' do
  original_my_service = MyService

  begin
    # Replace MyService with a double.
    MyService = double "should not receive any message"

    tested_method
  ensure
    # Restore MyService to original implementation.
    MyService = original_my_service
  end
end
```

If methods in MyService are called, it should raise:

```
RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: Double "should not receive any message" received unexpected message :some_method with (no args)
```

Comment: This works, but additionally requires surrounding the replacement and restoration of MyService with `$VERBOSE = nil`, `$VERBOSE = original_verbosity` to suppress the warnings when changing MyService.  But I like this approach since it does not require changing the original source to support the test.

Comment: If using active_support is acceptable, you could also wrap the double assignment step with `Kernel.silence_warnings do` from `active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting` to elegantly handle the suppression.

Comment: that's definitely an improvement

Answer (score 2):

If you inject the `MyService` dependency inside your object, you can substitute it with a mock with no methods defined on it, so that any method call will raise an exception.

Let me show you an example:

```
class Manager
  attr_reader :service

  def initialize(service = MyService)
    @service = service
  end

  def do_stuff
    service.do_stuff
  end

  def tested_method
    other_stuff
  end
end
```

And the tests would be:

```
context "#do_stuff" do
  let(:manager) { Manager.new }

  it 'invokes MyService by default' do
    MyService.should_receive(:do_stuff)
    manager.do_stuff
  end
end

context "#tested_method" do
  let(:service) { mock("FakeService") }
  let(:manager) { Manager.new(service) }

  it 'does not invoke any service' do
    expect { manager.tested_method }.not_to raise_error
  end
end
```

Comment: If there were a business logic reason to select the service programmatically, this would be a good approach, but I don't like the idea of doing this just to support testing.

Comment: Well, I think that tests make you understand which parts of your code are strictly coupled to each other: behaviours which are difficult to test are generally harder to change, so I think it is good to take hints from tests.

Comment: That's one generalisation, but another one is: YAGNI.   It introduces functionality that increases the complexity and "noise" of the implementation, which, if not needed for the application, ideally shouldn't be part of the implementation.

Comment: While I tend to agree with you about the meaning of "hard to test", sometimes, "it's hard to test" really is just a sign that the test system needs an additional feature :).

Comment: I guess I can understand your point of view, though lately I've been a huge supporter of the OpenClosed Principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle), so this example hit me as a 'classical' architecture which should be made open per extensions but closed for modification. I guess YAGNI is one thing, but I generally like to take the 'risk' of making my design more flexible, especially when it involves little effort. But I guess it involves a lot each own's personal taste!

Comment: This is a superior answer from an OO and code design perspective, however sometimes there are limitations which make the double hack (other answer) more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

```
it 'does not invoke MyService' do
    stub_const('MyService', double)
    tested_method
end
```

Any attempt to access `MyService` will return the mocked RSpec `double`. Since doubles raise errors when they receive messages that aren't explicitly stubbed (and none are being stubbed) *any* call to `MyService` will raise an error.

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/basics/test-doubles